# How to update data in Elasticsearch on a schedule?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I have a table in the **PostgreSQL** database. I want to insert data from that table into the **Elasticsearch**'s index. I need to update index data on a schedule. In other words, deletes old data and inserts with a new one. I have such **Logstash** configuration file but it doesn't update data in index. It's insert data but in the same time I see old data. Therefore, duplicate data occurs. How correctly to update data in Elasticsearch on a schedule?

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://host:port/postgres"
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        jdbc_password => "postgres"
        jdbc_driver_library => "postgresql-42.2.9.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM layers;"
        schedule => "0 0 * * MON"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "layers"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You index name doesnt change, so everytime you add new records, it adds to same index.

Add a datetime postfix to the index

```
index => "layers%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
```

So there'll be a new index for each date.

Now for searching, create an alias , so you can always use the same name in your application. For example: `layers/_search` by adding alias like below:

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "layers-2019.12.11",
        "alias": "layers"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Above step is via kibana or you can use http post. However, i'd recommend using [Curator for alias operations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/alias.html). That way once, log stash command completes, you can run curator to remove current index from the alias and add the newly created one.

Comment: As far as I understand, I will have `index` created for each day. All of them will be combined under the name of `alias`. In fact, in my application, I will need data from the last created index, the previous ones are not needed. How do I clean old indexes? I don't want to store garbage. There's no way to add new created index to the alias with logstash directly, right! The only way is to make POST request from some application, right?

Comment: Yes. You need to remove old and add new everyday. And you can use POST Or curator

Comment: Ok, but how I can remove old indexes? Can I make it from logstash directly?

Comment: No. Logstash will not remove index. Only  POST/ curl or curator

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I as you one more question before mark your answer as correct? Can you show me any example where I can remove all indexes except the last one by POST request or curator?

Comment: There’s an example on the link I added from elastic document. Also here’s another one I found that might help you to get started : https://ikeptwalking.com/managing-elasticsearch-aliases-using-curator/